# Convert to number

Tags: bash, shell

How do I convert a string to a number? The following Bash script does not work as expected.

```
#!/bin/sh

mynum="0.02"

if [[ $mynum -lt 1 ]];then
    echo "low"
else
    echo "high"
fi
```

**Error message**

> stack.sh: line 5: [[: 0.02: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".02")

Comment: Do you have to do this in Bourne Shell? If you are doing floating point arithmetic, you would be better off with Python, Perl, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `bash` normally only supports integer arithmetic; you will need to punt floating or complex math to `dc` or `bc`.

You may be able to cheat in this case:

```
case $mynum in
0 | 0.* | .* | -*)
    echo low
    ;;
*)
    echo high
    ;;
esac
```

But this obviously isn't generally applicable.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me. It's just the idea how you can use *[bc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language)*. Change the code as you wish.

```
mynum="1.02"

d=\`echo "$mynum-1" | bc\`
if [ "${d:0:1}" = "-" ]
then
    echo "low"
else
    echo "high"
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use "<"">" instead of `-lt` or `-gt`. For example:

```
a=0.09;[[ $a < 1 ]] && echo low ||echo big     
low
a=1.01;[[ $a < 1 ]] && echo low ||echo big    
big
```

Comment: It works in those cases, but it's not doing floating point arithmetic. That's just doing a string comparison. Try `a=11.1;[[ $a < 9 ]] && echo '$a < 9' || echo '$a >= 9'`

Comment: @l0b0 maybe there was sth. wrong.Another way,you can do `[ \`echo "$a < 9" |bc\` -eq 1 ]`